# Issue with Telerik RadTabStrip

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

Telerik Rad Tab Strip is not working in the nested Tab Strip. In the below code if i remove Required field validator everything is working fine but if it is added it is not working. How to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="TelerikTabStripControl.Home" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" MultiPageID="radMZendeskMultipage"
            SelectedIndex="0">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="Site Feautures" Width="250px">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="Two" Width="250px">
                </telerik:RadTab>
            </Tabs>
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
        <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="radMZendeskMultipage" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="siteConfig">
                Welcome 1
            </telerik:RadPageView>
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView2">
                Welcome 3
                <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="radChildTab" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1"
                    SelectedIndex="0">
                    <Tabs>
                        <telerik:RadTab Text="Child 1">
                        </telerik:RadTab>
                        <telerik:RadTab Text="Child 2">
                        </telerik:RadTab>
                    </Tabs>
                </telerik:RadTabStrip>
                <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadMulti">
                        USer Name
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserNAme" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="errormessage" ControlToValidate="UserNAme"
                            EnableClientScript="true" runat="server" />
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadMulti1">
                        LAst Name
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                </telerik:RadMultiPage>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting enableclientscript to false just to see what happens? Since the TextBox is in a RadMutlipage, have you tried adding an ajax manager and wiring up your textbox?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and it has to do with the RequiredFieldValidator now knowing which event to use.  I solved my issue by setting the ValidationGroup on my RequiredFieldValidator and submit button on my form so that the validation fires on that event.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug on radtabstrip. anyway, I solved it by changing the SelectIndex property from 0 to 1, which works correctly now.

```
 SelectedIndex="1"
```